# Can someone check my induction proof of $n^2 > 2n + 1$ for all $ n \geq 3$.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I have been studying proof by induction and I came across this proof:
Prove that for all integers $n ≥ 3$, $$n^2 > 2n + 1.$$

Proof: It’s obvious that the above statement holds for $n = 3$. Thus, we
can assume that it holds for $n = k$ and prove that it holds for $n = k+1$, which
means $(k + 1)^2 > 2(k + 1) + 1$, which is the same expression as $k^2 + 2k + 1 > 2k + 3$. Simplifying the expression leaves us with $k^2 > 2$. But since $n = k$ must be $≥ 3$, $k^2 > 2$, thus completing the proof. □

I checked the answer to the proof and it was different from mine. But I still fail to see what's wrong with my proof. Could someone please point it out for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to prove the statement in induction step, **using** the assumption from previous step...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak what is precisely meant by "use"? If you prove a base case, and then prove that $\alpha(n) \implies \alpha(n+1)$ by proving $\alpha(n+1)$ directly, and after this use the inductive property of the natural numbers to conclude that $\phi(n)$ is true for any $n$ greater than or equal to your base case, this is still a proof by induction

Comment: To @Carlyle: my English is poor. Next, I mean that using the assumption is mandatory. In other words, somewhere in the proof it is mandatory to use assumption $k^2>2k+1$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I disagree, unless one can formalise what is meant by "the induction hypothesis was used", it doesn't make sense to make this distinction, If the proof follows the general structure of proving $\alpha(0)$ and then proving $\alpha(n) \implies \alpha(n+1) $ and then applying the principle of mathematical induction to conclude $\alpha(n)$ for any $n$, then I see no reason to not call it an inductive proof. Particularly in this case since the induction hypothesis was itself true, it is equivalent to any other true statement, so if at any point the proof "uses" a true statement

Comment: ... then it has "used" a statement which is equivalent to the induction hypothesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing seriously wrong with your proof, in your inductive step however you end up just proving the statement directly, but there is nothing wrong with this as it does still prove the implication

$$ k^2 > 2k +1 
\implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1 $$

Which is technically what is required for a proof by induction, or at least for you to apply the statement of mathematical induction, but there are some things you might want to improve on in the proof of the inductive step:

Usually, "expression" is used to refer to some combination of symbols and operations and relations between them. Two expressions are the same when they are...the same... so the *expression*

$$ x+1 $$

Is not the same as

$$ x+1+0$$

But in some contexts, these expressions are associated with the same object. What you were comparing are what is usually referred to as *statements*, and we don't talk about statements being the same, but rather about statements being equivalent to another, or some statement implying another. This is an important distinction because if one were to interpret your proof entirely formally you would probably venture that what you meant is this:

\begin{align}
&(k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) +1 \\\\
\implies & k^2 +2k + 1 > 2k + 3 \\\\
\implies & k^2 > 2 \\\\
\impliedby & k>3 \\
\end{align}

And since we know $k>3$, we can conclude

$$ (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) +1 $$

And *this* proof is definitely not correct, since

$\alpha \implies \beta$

and

$\gamma \implies \beta $

does not mean that

$\gamma \implies \alpha $

If $\implies $ is still an unfamiliar concept for you, you can imagine thinking of statements as being on different "heights", if $\alpha \implies \beta$ then $\alpha$ is higher than $\beta$, and now it's clear why this doesn't make any sense. If I am higher than Bob, and you are higher than Bob, we can't conclude anything about the relative height between you and me. this can be fixed if at every step you replace $\implies$ with $\iff$, since

\begin{align}
&(k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1 \\\\
\iff & k^2 + 2k +1 > 2k + 3 \\\\
\end{align}

For example, and indeed this may have been what you meant when you said the expressions are the same, but for the sake of clarity it is probably better to start with a statement that you know, and end with the statement that you want to conclude through a chain of implications, so a rewritten version of your proof could be:

Since $k>3$ we know that $k^2>2$, and so we can conclude that

$$ k^2+ 2k > 2k + 2 $$

And so adding $1$ on both sides,

$$ k^2 + 2k + 1 > 2k+ 3 $$

But this implies that

$$ (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1 $$

And so the implication

$$ k> 3 \land k^2 > 2k+1 \\ \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1 $$

Is true, which allows you to conclude using the principle of mathematical induction that

$$ n^2 > 2n+1 $$

For any $n>3$.

Here it is entirely clear that I proved the implication, and there is no room for incorrect interpretation, however, it is entirely unnecessary to use induction here, but induction was technically used. You'll have to ask your course convenor if they would accept such a proof, some might appreciate you noticing that it is still technically inductive, and others might be confused by what you're even asking, in which case it is better to follow the type of approach given in one of the other ansers

Comment: @Carlye Thank you so much for your answer. I was also thinking "Since my proof looks valid, I must have used the right technique" which wasn't the case. And yes, my proof does need some clarification. and is open to misinterpretation I'm still new to proofwriting, so it's something I want to work on. Thanks again.

Comment: @KidusAyalew yes it takes some getting used to, but once you have a firm grasp of what it means to prove an implication, and how to combine different implications, it becomes easier, its perhaps a good idea to challenge yourself by trying to write your proofs in some (slightly more) formal language

Comment: That's indeed a good idea. I hope I'll get the hang of it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not a proof by induction !

In order to do a proof by induction you should be proving that

> For $n = 3$
> $$ n^2 > 2 n + 1$$
> and for  all $k \geq 3 :$ $$ k^2 >2k + 1 \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) +1$$

You can check out A Sahoo's answer to see such a proof.

Instead of this you have proven

> For $n = 3$
> $$ n^2 > 2 n + 1$$
> and
> $$ k \geq 3 \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) +1.$$

by using the fact that

> $k \geq 3 \implies k^2 > 2 $ and
> $ k^2 \geq 2 \iff (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) +1.$

In particular you proof does have as a consequence that for all  $n \geq 3$ we have
$$ n^2 > 2n + 1$$
but it is not a proof by induction.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see. I was just focusing on whether my proof was valid or not, not that I used the right method. Thank you so much for your answer; it helped a lot.

Comment: I am not sure I agree, they used the words "assume $k^2>2k+1$, and then proceeded to prove (also assuming $k\geq 3$) that $(k+1)^2 > 2(k+1)+1 $, so have they not technically proven the implication $ k\geq 3 \land k^2 > 2k +1 \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1 $? Their proof is valid independent of the assumption of  $k^2> 2k+1$, but they technically did still assume it

Comment: @Carlyle OP's proof is poorly written which does not help us understand what he actually proved or not. Do you seriously believe that the OP actually meant to prove $k \geq 3 \wedge k^2 > 2k +1 \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1$ ?  I'm really not convinced that is the case. He's a novice who struggles with writing a proof by induction. I'm more inclined to think that he meant to  prove $k \geq 3 \implies (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1) + 1$ and ... (1/)

Comment: @Carlyle and mindlessly copied "Thus, we can assume that it holds for n=k
 and prove that it holds for n=k+1" from his textbook which, by a technicality, makes his proof into a proof by induction. I think we would be doing a disservice to him if we were to accept his proof as a proof by induction based on a such a technicality. Certainly if he is novice. (2/...)

Comment: @Digitallis you do make a valid point, but I think we would also be doing them a disservice if we tell them that this is not a proof by induction, as this isn't the entire story either. I think the best is to be honest and tell them that it is a proof by induction, but not a good one, and not one which should be taken as a reference for future proofs of this kind (but I must admit that the disservice you mention is much greater than the one I mention)

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming the consequent:
If your induction assumption is:
$k^2>2k+1$

You can not start from:
$(k+1)^2>2(k+1)+1$

Since this is what you have to prove.
Start from your assumption:
$k^2>2k+1$

Now adding the same number to both sides does not change the inequality:

$k^2+2k+1>2k+1+2k+1=2(2k+1)$
Now:

$4k+2-(2(k+1)+1)=2k-1>0$

Thus:
$(k+1)^2>2(k+1)+1$

Answer (score -1):

According to induction hypothesis the statement is true for $n=k$ i.e., $k^2 > 2k+1$. Now we have to show it is true for $n=k+1$ i.e., $(k + 1)^2 > 2(k + 1) + 1$.
\begin{align*}
(k + 1)^2 &= k^2+2k+1\\
      &> (2k+1)+2k+1  ~ ~ ~  ~ ~ [\text{From induction hypothesis } k^2 > 2k+1]\\ 
     &= 2k + 2k + 2\\
      &= 2(k + 1) + 2k\\
&>2(k + 1) + 1 ~ ~ ~  ~ ~ [\text{Since } 2k > 1, ~\forall k\geq 3]
\end{align*}
Therefore, we get $(k + 1)^2 > 2(k + 1) + 1$ for all $k \geq 3$.

Comment: You did not use the induction hypothesis at all. And the final conclusion should just be that $(k+1)^2>2(k+1)+1$.

Comment: @Digitallis It is there *now*, but not when I wrote my comment.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com :) Though your answer is relevant it actually does not answer the question asked by the user.  Could you add more more detail in order to fully answer the user's question which is "But I still fail to see what's wrong with my proof. Could someone please point it out for me?"